# AWS DynamoDB Android defining key for a table

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm developing a basic forum Android app where users can post a question and other users of the community can leave a reply and I'm using DynamoDB to store "forum" data, but as database will be possibly read / written by thousands or millions of users I'm a little bit "worried" about performance.

I have read a lot about defining a key but cannot make my mind clear on the best solution according DynamoDB way of working. I'm thinking on two possibilities, the first is defining question_id (UUID) as Hash Key with no Range Key and create an index like category_id / index (category is the category of the question and index is used for sorting by date) and the second could be defining category_id as hash key with index as range key and no secondary index (with this second option I avoid creating a secondary index).

Could you please help me in clearing my mind about what could be best in terms of performance?

Edited just to be more clear:

My scenario is a little bit complex (in fact it's not complex with a common relational database system but DynamoDB has many limitations, specially for paginating forward and backwards) and what I need is the next:

A user posts a question and this question is stored in database (no problem with that) then in the "Questions List" screen I should be able to list questions grouped by category and paginated and sorted by date (here it starts to be a little more complicated) so I created an index attribute  (because I know an index will be consecutive according to posting order (date) and then it will be sorted by date) and I have a secondary index where I use category + index attribute as a key and this way I filter by category and sort by index (let's say date) and I also use the index to paginate.

All this "invention" is working great, but what, I'm testing with a single user and posting one question at a time but don't know what will happen with thousands or millions of users and in what about optimization / performance concerns I'd like to be sure I'm using the best table key definition schema.

My actual key definition for questions table is category + index (other fields are subject, question, timestamp, userid, etc), so with this added information I hope anyone can give me some hints on if I'm going in the right direction.

Comment: you no need to worry about performance .... because its a google's server ...
you just write as much as possible efficient code/logic

Comment: can not be category_id would be unique for every question .. so question_id could be unique .... you can also set it as autoGenerateKey in your java mapper class

Comment: Thanks for replying nightcoder. DynamoDB is AWS (Amazon, not Google) and the way it works is different from a relational database, as it is not a relational one and it uses a hash key and a sort key to define a key and it doesn't matter is hash key is duplicated, is combination of hash kay and sort key what cannot be duplicated.

Comment: oops lols .... yep i know that it is nosql ... I worked with dynamodb ... and when i used to update any task .. I need to get the unique key for it .... but in my app I could not make unique key for every task...
so i used autoGenerate for this purpose in Dynamodb

Comment: Thank you very much again nightcoder. Please check my edited post when you have time.